# Adding Date to MySQL using PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am building a e-commerce back end. I am attempting to add a "estimated date of delivery" to a HTML table.

All its doing is adding 14 days to the order date. How do I add 14 days to a php variable that's a time. Here's my code:

```
$order_date = mysql_result($order_results, $a, "order_date"); 

$convert_orderDate = strtotime($order_date);

$order_date = date('m-d-y', $convert_orderDate);
```

I want to change `$order_date` to `$etd` (estimated time of delivery) by simply adding 14 days to `$order_date`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Do it in MySQL directly:

```
SELECT order_date + INTERVAL 14 DAY AS order_date
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. I have the code in a big while loop. Here i sthe full code: `$a=0;
    while ($a < $num_rows){
 $order_date = mysql_result($order_results, $a, "order_date");
 $convert_orderDate = strtotime($order_date);
 $order_date = date('m-d-y', $convert_orderDate); 
 $etd_query = "SELECT $order_date + INTERVAL 14 DAY AS $order_date";
 $etd =  mysql_query($etd_query);`

Comment: mysql_query returns a result handle - you have to FETCH a row from that result to get the actual data.

Comment: You have the value of `$order_date` in your `SELECT` statement. Should be `"SELECT order_date ..."` **not** `"SELECT $order_date ..."`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and the modify() method

```
$etd = new DateTime($order_date);
$etd->modify('+14 Days');
echo $etd->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question based on your code example, you can do it with `strtotime`. I've tested this code:

```
$order_date = '2012-08-14';

$convert_orderDate = strtotime($order_date);
$convert_etd       = strtotime($order_date . ' + 14 days');

$order_date = date('m-d-Y', $convert_orderDate);
$order_etd  = date('m-d-Y', $convert_etd);

echo $order_date; // 08-14-2012
echo $order_etd;  // 08-28-2012
```

Comment: That didn't work when I tried I got This: 07-01-12 (original order date) gave me this answer 1169794800 using your code. Here is the code I used `$etd = strtotime($order_date . ' + 14 days');`

Comment: Your date format is ambiguous, how is order_date formatted when you get it from the database?

Comment: If your date is 07-01-12 you are not storing it in the database in the correct format. You should be using a date field in the table and the standard format is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: I got it too work, I will update the with the answer in my code... thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it to work:

```
$a=0;
while ($a < $num_rows){ //while loop to go through all rows and print data

      $order_date = mysql_result($order_results, $a, "order_date");// pulls order date

      $convert_orderDate = strtotime($order_date); //converts order_date
      $convert_etd       = strtotime($order_date . ' + 14 days'); //converts etd by adding to order date

      $order_date = date('m-d-y', $convert_orderDate); // reformats order date
      $order_etd  = date('m-d-Y', $convert_etd); // reformats etd

echo"<td>$order_date</td>
     <td>$order_etd</td>";
```

Thanks guys this works perfectly! Thanks @JDavis